# Failed to send mail in my contact form

Tags: php, html

I have designed a form to receive feedback from my site visitors.I have developed the site,but the mail send option is not working properly..I receive the error "Mail is not send". Can anybody help me to solve this...

My Php code

```
    <?php
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$company=$_POST['company'];
$name=$_POST['name'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$message=$_POST['message'];
$mobile=$_POST['mobile'];    

$to='www@gmail.com'; 
$headers="From: $company";
$mail=mail($to,$company,$name,$mobile,$email);
if($mail) { echo'Mail send successfully'; }
else { echo'Mail is not send'; }
}    
?>
```

And here is my HTML form

```
<form id="contact-form" action="" role="form" method="post">
            <div class="contact-form-loader"></div>
            <fieldset>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="grid_5">

          <label class="company">
                    <input type="text" name="company" placeholder="Company name" required/>

                  </label>

                  <label class="name">
                    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your name" required/>

                  </label>
                  <label class="mobile">
                    <input type="text" name="mobile" placeholder="Your mobile" required/>

                  </label>
                  <label class="email">
                    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Your email" value="" required/>

                  </label>

                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="grid_6">
                  <label class="message">
                    <textarea name="message" placeholder="Any remarks?"></textarea>

                  </label>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="contact-form-buttons">
                <input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" class="sub">
              </div>
            </fieldset>
          </form>
```

help me solve this

Comment: Are you using local server ..??

Comment: i tried in both local and live server...its not working still @ squiroid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
$mail=mail($to,$company,$name,$mobile,$email);
```

to

```
mail($to,$subject,$txt,$headers);
```

And mail has only four parameters(mainly) that's why `$mail=mail($to,$company,$name,$mobile,$email);` returns false and you got the else part "`{ echo'Mail is not send'; }`"

```
so in your $txt=$company."\n".$name."\n".$email."\n".$message."\n".$mobile;
```

Comment: It works fine. But it shows as trimmed content ..how to avoid it @squiroid

Comment: You need to format it properly according to your requirement.
Tutorial :- http://www.developphp.com/page.php?id=318
And please up vote and select the answer if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the parameters of the php mail function.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Try

```
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

$mail=mail($to,'Your mail subject',$message,$headers);
```

Answer (score 0):

the signature of php mail function is like this

mail($to,$subject,$body,$additionalHeaders,$additionalParameters);

please go through this url for more information http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

```
$to='www@gmail.com'; 
$headers="From: $company";
/* you have to add email and phone into your message. */
$mail=mail($to,'subject of your mail',$message, $headers);
if($mail) { echo'Mail send successfully'; }
else { echo'Mail is not send'; }
}    
?>  
try this
Happy coding :)
```